# Why does chatterbot raise TypeError for my custom corpus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

Yesterday, I discovered Chatterbot, which allows you to create bots, so after I installed *chatterbot-corpus*, I trained the chatterbot with *chatterbot.corpus.english*. I then tried to train it with my custom corpus,  but when I tried to train it, it raise this error:

```
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.custom')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 154, in train
    statement_search_text = self.chatbot.storage.tagger.get_bigram_pair_string(text)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 21, in get_bigram_pair_string
    if len(text) <= 2:
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Here is what my chatterbot code looks like:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
chatterbot = ChatBot('test')
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatterbot)
trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.custom.random')
```

random.yml looks like this:

```
categories:
- random
conversations:
- - r u gae
  - not as gae as you
  - no
- - ye
  - nuu
- - 1 + 1 =
  - the largest value that can be expressed as an exponential function
- - you are dumb
  - yes, but not as dumb as you
```

I tested this out with another custom corpus I made, and somehow that works. How do I fix this error?

Comment: That "no" on the sixth line of your YAML is being interpreted as a boolean value, I think.  Try putting it in quotes.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really know YAML, so..